# New to SSRS - Where is the Report Designer

Tags: reporting-services

I just watched a video regarding the Report Designer.  It said to go to Start, Programs, Microsoft SQL Server 2008, Reporting Services, and then select the Report Designer.  I'm certain I installed everything, but I do not have this program.

I have VS2008 Professional Version installed and SQL Server 2008.

I can open a Report Project and build a report in VS2008, but the IDE does not look the same.  She built a simple report using the designer, pointed it at AdventureWorks2008, and published it.

Is there a difference?  Is it a seperate download?

Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Randy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Report Designer is hosted in the Business Intelligence Development Studio, which is fully integrated with the Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 development environment. If you do not have Visual Studio 2008 installed, SQL Server Setup installs the shell so that you can run Report Designer. For more information, see Reporting Services in Business Intelligence Development Studio.

To use Report Designer, open the Start menu, point to Programs, point to Microsoft SQL Server 2008, and select Business Intelligence Development Studio. After you open Business Intelligence Development Studio, you can open or create a new project template. When you select a Report Server Project, the Report Designer opens. The design surface tabbed windows, and graphical tools appear when you add a report to the project. For more information, see Working with Report Designer in Business Intelligence Development Studio.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157166.aspx

Comment: Is this the same Report Designer?  The IDE that she demo'd looked different.  It had less menu options.  

Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Without seeming the demo it is hard to say.  She could have been using an older version, but likely it was the shell version that she was showing which would account for the lack of options.  She wasn't demoing the Report Builder tool was she?

Comment: Here is the url to her video on YouTube.  

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YfUp4pb2R7Y

I'm going to try to send her the question and find out what she is using.  This is not a priority, I'm just trying to get a better handle on SSRS.

I really appreciate your help.

Randy

Answer (score 1):

If you installed VS2008 then SQL Server 2008, then you should have some new projects in VS2008 so you can build a Reporting Service.

Otherwise you can go to the Start -> ... -> SQL Server -> Business Intelligence Studio, to design the report.

Comment: You will find that BIRT will go to VS2008 if you have it installed for that, so you might as well use VS and just create the project there.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but for everyone else that is looking for it (as was I): I think you mean the Report Builder, it can be found here: 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/nl-nl/details.aspx?FamilyId=d3173a87-7c0d-40cc-a408-3d1a43ae4e33

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you would get the same generic error if you try to access the URL via any other browser other than IE running as Admin.